# Error in loading .Rdata in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, workspace

I am trying to load my workspace in Rstudio and I get this error:

```
Error: ReadItem: unknown type 192, perhaps written by later version of R
```

I used the very same file a few days ago. I do not understand what might have happened. I have extremely important data inside that workspace that it is imperative to get! Any help is highly welcome.

Comment: Perhaps try 'attach("file_name.RData")`

Comment: It returns the same error!